# Mindmap Tikz fit size

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, mindmaps

I would like to fit all text into nodes to my mindmap diagram

[image]

I have tried with "text width" but I do want different sizes for nodes (depending on parent/children relationship). Also would like to change my font to a different weight.

```
    documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={concept, rectangle, minimum size=0.5cm, inner sep=0.2mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\tikz[mindmap,concept color=blue!70]
\node [concept] {Wind turbine Monitoring}
child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {
    node[concept] {Blades}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=30] {node[concept] {Vbrations}}
    child[grow=150] {node[concept] {Loads:Bending Moments}} 
    }
child[grow=150,concept color=blue!70] {
    node[concept] {Tower}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {node[concept] {Bending Moments}}
    child[grow=150] {node[concept] {Oscillations}}
    }
child[grow=270] {
    node[concept] {Drive Train}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=-90] {
    node[concept] {Vibration}
    child[grow=-90] {node[concept] {acceleration}}
    }
    child[grow=150,concept color=blue!50] {
        node[concept] {Loads}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child[grow=-150,concept color=blue!50] {node[concept]                       {Fatigue}}
        }
    child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {node[concept] {Oil                    Particles}}
    }
;
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

At the end I would like to use this picture to a *.ppt presentation so the size of nodes and text is important to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is adding different `text width`s for different nodes out of the question? To change font properties for a node use e.g. `font=\bfseries` in a style/node options, or use `\textbf{...}` directly in the node. And unrelated: why have `concept` in `every node/.append style`, the options to the `\tikz`-picture and as an option to each individual node? One of the three is likely enough ...

Comment: The point is that I want to clarify that the size of nodes depending on their level. But we could manually change the node width though.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style according to level with the `level N concept` styles, as described in the manual, section 58.2. (`N` is an integer, counting from 1.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mindmap,
  concept color=blue!70,
  every node/.append style={concept,inner sep=0.2mm},
  level 1 concept/.append style={text width=2.5cm,font=\small},
  level 2 concept/.append style={text width=2cm,font=\scriptsize},
  level 3 concept/.append style={text width=1cm,font=\tiny\bfseries},
]
\node {Wind turbine Monitoring}
child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {
    node {Blades}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=30] {node {Vibrations}}
    child[grow=150] {node {Loads: Bending Moments}} 
    }
child[grow=150,concept color=blue!70] {
    node {Tower}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {node {Bending Moments}}
    child[grow=150] {node {Oscillations}}
    }
child[grow=270] {
    node {Drive Train}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[grow=-90] {
    node {Vibration}
    child[grow=-90] {node {accel\-eration}} % note \- to indicate hyphenation point
    }
    child[grow=150,concept color=blue!50] {
        node {Loads}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child[grow=-150,concept color=blue!50] {node  {Fatigue}}
        }
    child[grow=30,concept color=blue!50] {node {Oil Particles}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```